# Should same web api serve both UI SPA and mobile clients?

Tags: angularjs, rest, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application, restful-architecture

If we have a SPA App built with angularjs for example that use (REST API) web api service for it's requests is it ok or better qustion is should other mobile clients use same api for theirs request?

Comment: are you trying to ask the same question you asked earlier in a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer having one API usable by multiple clients when possible so as to avoid having to duplicate code. The client should be responsible for making sure it can use your API (one API, multiple clients) rather than the API being responsible for making sure the clients can use it (multiple APIs for multiple clients).